# Removing terminal dependency for a flask web application

Tags: python, linux, flask, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have a flask web server running on the cloud and the process goes down if I close the terminal or if my local machine loses network connection. So how can I make sure that my flask process runs forever with out any dependency on the terminal? And is there any way to monitor the process. Like for example if I log in again and go to a URL I get all the details I need.

Comment: You want to deamonize the process to keep it running. It's common to use something like supervisord to manage the web server process. https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `screen` command. Let's assume that your application is `app.py` and the steps are as follows.

1.Create a new session and it will write screen output to a file named `screenlog.0`.

```
screen -L
```

2.Now you are in a session and you can run your application.

```
python app.py
```

3.Detach this session.

```
Press "Ctrl-A" and then press "D" on your keyboard to detach the session.
```

Then you will return your normal terminal. Your application is running in the background in a virtual screen and all screen output will be written to the file `screenlog.0`. You can close your terminal without affecting your application.

4.Reattach to the previous session.

If you want to shut down your application or to do some other things, you can use command `screen -r` to reattach to the previous session.

5.Terminate a session.

After attaching to a session, just use `exit` to terminate it.

**For more details, please read [this tutorial](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/).**